# Smooth jagged pixels

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, pixel-manipulation

I've created a pinch filter/effect on canvas using the following algorithm:

```
// iterate pixels
for (var i = 0; i < originalPixels.data.length; i+= 4) {

    // calculate a pixel's position, distance, and angle
    var pixel = new Pixel(affectedPixels, i, origin);

    // check if the pixel is in the effect area
    if (pixel.dist < effectRadius) {

        // initial method (flawed)
        // iterate original pixels and calculate the new position of the current pixel in the affected pixels
        if (method.value == "org2aff") {

            var targetDist = ( pixel.dist - (1 - pixel.dist / effectRadius) * (effectStrength * effectRadius) ).clamp(0, effectRadius);
            var targetPos  = calcPos(origin, pixel.angle, targetDist);

            setPixel(affectedPixels, targetPos.x, targetPos.y, getPixel(originalPixels, pixel.pos.x, pixel.pos.y));

        } else {

            // alternative method (better)
            // iterate affected pixels and calculate the original position of the current pixel in the original pixels
            var originalDist = (pixel.dist + (effectStrength * effectRadius)) / (1 + effectStrength);
            var originalPos  = calcPos(origin, pixel.angle, originalDist);

            setPixel(affectedPixels, pixel.pos.x, pixel.pos.y, getPixel(originalPixels, originalPos.x, originalPos.y));

        }

    } else {
        // copy unaffected pixels from original to new image
        setPixel(affectedPixels, pixel.pos.x, pixel.pos.y, getPixel(originalPixels, pixel.pos.x, pixel.pos.y));
    }
}
```

I've struggled a lot to get it to this point and I'm quite happy with the result. Nevertheless, I have a small problem; jagged pixels. Compare the JS pinch with Gimp's:

[image]

I don't know what I'm missing. Do I need to apply another filter after the actual filter? Or is my algorithm wrong altogether?

---

I can't add the full code here (as a SO snippet) because it contains 4 base64  images/textures (65k chars in total). Instead, here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/6pmgkj95/).

Comment: It looks like method2 is your implementation of Kruga's idea from [your codereview question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174786/pinch-an-image-in-canvas) - The big difference between method2 and gimp is that gimp's image is full of antialiasing.  I wonder, if method2 is, for each destination pixel, calculating the weighted avg of the source pixels, can you vary the shade of grey used for the dest pixel accordingly?  That should approach the gimp result.

Comment: Correct. I've seen the method2 in action with rotation, and gave it a go in my code. As you and Alex pointed out, I think I also need to apply a second filter/interpolation/anti-aliasing, or whatever it is called. First, I'll do an extensive research on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

One way to clean up the result is supersampling. Here's a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lawmo4q8/

Basically, instead of calculating a single value for a single pixel, you take multiple value samples within/around the pixel...

```
let color =
    calcColor(x - 0.25, y - 0.25) + calcColor(x + 0.25, y - 0.25) +
    calcColor(x - 0.25, y + 0.25) + calcColor(x + 0.25, y + 0.25);
```

...and merge the results in some way.

```
color /= 4;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the demo, but I don't think it is that simple. I'm trying to implement your method, but I fail. I think you're using `calcColor` to create that wave shape, and when sampling, you're using the same function. In my case, I need to be able to work with already created shape, i.e., `imageData` (pixels). I've created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/8oLv6wkh/), but my result isn't as smooth as yours. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It really is that simple. If you have a function that maps a pixel in the output image to a pixel in the input image, all you have to do is sample multiple input pixels for each output pixel.

Comment: I'm already doing that, I think, and it doesn't really work. I must be missing something. Can I request that you check the demo I provided? I've written it simply, so I doubt you'll have trouble noticing the problem.  If you compare the results, you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: It works just fine, as your demo shows. You can get a slightly better result by using a weighted kernel (i.e., gaussian, https://jsfiddle.net/8oLv6wkh/5/), and increasing the size of the kernel, but this is pretty much as good as it gets when you are sampling from a limited resolution. There are additional things you can do if you know for a fact that 2 colors is all you have to deal with, but it seems to me you're looking for a generic approach.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of applying a successive filter it is best to do oversampling directly in the pinch algorithm. (instead of calculating a single pixel do it to more slightly shifted pixels and average)

Another option is to upscale the original image, run your algorithm, and scale down the image interpolating the pixels.